# Android Studio checkstyle task

Tags: android, android-studio, checkstyle

I have an project (multi-module) in which I use checkstyle task. This is the relevant configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
check.dependsOn 'checkstyle'

// Set the directory for quality config files
def configDir = "${project.rootDir}/quality_tools"
// Set the directory for quality reports
def reportsDir = "${project.buildDir}/reports"

checkstyle {
    toolVersion = "7.6"

    configFile file("$configDir/checkstyle/google_checks.xml")
    configProperties.checkstyleSuppressionsPath = file("$configDir/checkstyle/suppressions.xml").absolutePath
}

@ParallelizableTask
class ParallelCheckstyle extends Checkstyle {}

task checkstyle(type: ParallelCheckstyle, group: 'verification') {
    description 'Runs Checkstyle inspection against Android sourcesets.'

    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'
    exclude '**/test/**'
    exclude '**/androidTest/**'
    exclude '**/R.java'
    exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'

    classpath = files()
}
```

This gives me the following error:

> Execution failed for task ':domain:checkstyle'.
>   Unable to create Root Module: configLocation {[my_project_path]\quality_tools\checkstyle\google_checks.xml}, classpath {null}.

If I downgrade the tool version to 7.4 it seems to work fine.
Is there a way to make it work with the latest version, or can anyone let me know if I did something wrong in the configuration?

Thank you.

Comment: I've updated `google_checks` with the latest version and it seems to be working now.
I'm using the style from here: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml

The error was misleading, it seems some of the properties are not supported anymore (or they were replaced).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the `checkstyle` task fails because of the properties of the config file.
I've updated to the latest version of [google_checks.xm](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml) and it works fine now.

The error description was missleading.